# count number of string per row in a column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, count

Inside my dataframe:

```
no    pre_code
1     23, 234, 345
2     234, 345
3     23
4     NaN
```

I want to count number of string inside `pre_code` columns, What I have tried so far was:

```
df['count'] = df['pre_code'].astype('str').str.split(',').str.len().fillna(0)
```

but with the code above, it counts NaN as 1. So, I dont get the desired results.

Before, I also have tried this way:

```
df['count'] = df['pre_code'].str.count(',').add(1).fillna(0)
```

Unfortunately, the code above also did not work on my dataframe. It gives me 0 for the single entry string. For your information, I have 2200 rows on my dataframe, and somehow the code could not work perfectly for those number of rows. When I tried for only 5 rows, somehow it worked well.

I expect the result would be like:

```
no    pre_code         count
1     23, 234, 345       3
2     234, 345           2
3     23                 1
4     NaN                0
```

any solution for my case?

thanks in advance.

Comment: you asked this question somewhere else before. Did you try the list comprehension? Either ways, the code above should work. Kindly update your example to show the lines where the code above fails

Comment: What is the type of `23, 234, 345` and the type of `NaN` please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `nan` like `np.nan` instead string `nan`, then both solutions working correct:

You need test how looks values without numbers for replacement:

```
print (df.loc[~df['pre_code'].str.contains('\d'), 'pre_code'].unique().tolist())
['nan']
```

---

```
df['count'] = df['pre_code'].replace('nan', np.nan).str.split(',').str.len().fillna(0)
```

Or:

```
df['count'] = df['pre_code'].replace('nan', np.nan).str.count(',').add(1).fillna(0)

print (df)
   no      pre_code  count
0   1  23, 234, 345    3.0
1   2      234, 345    2.0
2   3            23    1.0
3   4           NaN    0.0
```

EDIT:

EDIT: More general solution is convert values without numbers to `NaN` in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['count'] = (df['pre_code'].where(df['pre_code'].str.contains('\d', na=False))
                             .str.count(',')
                             .add(1)
                             .fillna(0)
                             .astype(int))
print (df)
   no      pre_code  count
0   1  23, 234, 345      3
1   2      234, 345      2
2   3            23      1
3   4           NaN      0
```

Comment: I have tried that way but it still gives me 0 for the single string

Comment: @yangyang - What is `print (df.loc[~df['pre_code'].str.contains('\d'), 'pre_code'].unique().tolist())` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['count'] = df.loc[df['pre_code'].notna(), 'pre_code'] \
                .astype(str).str.split(',').str.len() \
                .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)

print(df)

# Output:
   no      pre_code  count
0   1  23, 234, 345      3
1   2      234, 345      2
2   3            23      1
3   4           NaN      0
```

I'm not sure you have to convert to str (`astype(str)).